# Problem in calculating the symmetric normalised laplacian matrix

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, algebra

I found some problems in calculating the symmetric normalised laplacian matrix in python.
Suppose to have the matrix S and its diagonal degree matrix D:

```
    [ [ 1 , 0.5, 0.2]        [ [1.7, 0, 0 ]
S =   [0.5,  1 , 0.5]     D =  [ 0 , 2, 0 ] 
      [0.2, 0.5,  1 ] ]        [ 0 , 0,1.7] ]
```

When calculating L as

[image: Laplace normalised equation]

I obtain this result:

```
       [[ 0.41176471 -0.27116307 -0.11764706]
    L = [-0.27116307  0.5        -0.27116307]
        [-0.11764706 -0.27116307  0.41176471]]
```

Using this code:

```
S = np.array([[1,0.5,0.2],[0.5,1,0.5],[0.2,0.5,1]])

print("Similiarity Matrix: \n",S)
print("\n\n")


D = np.zeros((len(S), len(S)))
#H = np.sum(G[0])
for id, x in enumerate(S):
    D[id][id] = np.sum(x)

I = np.identity(len(S))

L = I - ((sqrtm(inv(D))).dot(S)).dot(sqrtm(inv(D)))
print("\n\n")
print("Laplacian normalized: \n",L)
```

This differ from using the function `csgraph.laplacian(S, normed=True)` that return:

```
       [[[ 1.        -0.5976143  -0.28571429]
    L = [-0.5976143   1.         -0.5976143 ]
        [-0.28571429 -0.5976143   1.        ]]
```

why this happen? Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the ratio between the unnormalized and normalized matrixes returned by `csgraph.laplacian` is closely related to the ratio of the unnormalized matrix and your `L`:

```
In [20]: csgraph.laplacian(S, normed=False) / L - 1
Out[20]:
array([[0.7       , 0.84390889, 0.7       ],
       [0.84390889, 1.        , 0.84390889],
       [0.7       , 0.84390889, 0.7       ]])

In [21]: csgraph.laplacian(S, normed=False) / csgraph.laplacian(S, normed=True)
Out[21]:
array([[0.7       , 0.83666003, 0.7       ],
       [0.83666003, 1.        , 0.83666003],
       [0.7       , 0.83666003, 0.7       ]])
```

0.84390889 ≠ 0.83666003 but other numbers match. Could the difference be simply due to normalization?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know. I think that this difference is too small to make such a big discrepancy in those two matrices, but i'm not sure at all.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have 1s in the diagonal of `S`:

```
# weighted adjacency
S = np.array([[1,0.5,0.2],[0.5,1,0.5],[0.2,0.5,1]])

np.fill_diagonal(S, 0.0)

# strength diagonal matrix
D = np.diag(np.sum(S,axis=1))

# identity
I = np.identity(S.shape[0])

# D^{-1/2} matrix
D_inv_sqrt = np.linalg.inv(np.sqrt(D))

L = I - np.dot(D_inv_sqrt, S).dot(D_inv_sqrt)

L

array([[ 1.        , -0.5976143 , -0.28571429],
       [-0.5976143 ,  1.        , -0.5976143 ],
       [-0.28571429, -0.5976143 ,  1.        ]])
```

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate why this action is better than doing the operation on the matrix with the ones already in the adjacency matrix? Would love to know!

Comment: @intStdu The notes taken from scipy official repo: "Diagonal entries of the input adjacency matrix are ignored and replaced with zeros for the purpose of normalization where ``normed=True``. The normalization uses the inverse square roots of row-sums of the input adjacency matrix, and thus may fail if the row-sums contain zeros, negative, or complex with a non-zero imaginary part values." [https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_laplacian.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_laplacian.py)

Comment: @intStdu However, such notes are missing in the API reference [https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.laplacian.html](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.laplacian.html). It is really really a pitfall, and I fall into it. I think it would be better if they add a parameter ``remove_diag = True`` in the function parameters list, and replace ``inf`` to zero when calculated inverse square root.